# From Ruby array to JS array in Rails- 'quote'?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, json

I have a Ruby array like this in my controller:

```
 @location_list = [
        ['Mushrooms', 3],
        ['Onions', 1],
        ['Olives', 1], 
        ['Zucchini', 1],
        ['Pepperoni', 2]
      ]
```

And I am catching it like this in my view:

```
location_list = "<%= @location_list.to_json %>";
```

But if I do alert(location_list), I get:

```
[[&quot;Mushrooms&quot;,3],[&quot;Onions&quot;,1],[&quot;Olives&quot;,1],[&quot;Zucchini&quot;,1],[&quot;Pepperoni&quot;,2]]
```

How do I get the correspondent object without those &quot?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try:

```
<%= raw @location_list.as_json %>
```

Using `to_json` will end up rendering a string, with embedded double-quotes, and would need to be JS-escaped. And it would be a string, not an array.

Comment: I tried that. The main problem is that when doing either raw or html_safe I see 'Unexpected identifier' (in the console) when trying to use that var.  Even though if I see the source I can see this: var location_list = "[["Mushrooms",3],["Onions",1],["Olives",1],["Zucchini",1],["Pepperoni",2]]";
console.log(location_list); -- What can be happening?

Comment: @HommerSmith How are you trying to use it? Also, if it's actually quoted like that, it's a string--not an array; did you try `as_json`?

Comment: I am just trying to show it in the console...Basically I want to pass an array from Ruby to JS...If I change the ruby array to be like this:  @location_list = [1,3,4] -- I don't get that error. It's just when there are strings inside the array that I get 'Unexpected identifier' in my chrome console.

Comment: @HommerSmith I'm saying if it's quoted like that, it's going to be an error--can't you see that a double-quoted string with embedded double quotes is a JS syntax error? That's why I said to use `as_json`, which won't quote it.

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me:

```
<%= @location_list.to_s.gsub(''', '') %>
```

Basically use `.to_s` to convert the whole array to a string, then use `.gsub(''','')` to remove the quotes by replacing them with nothing.